# Can high energy photons produce more photo current than a bit more intensity of photo electrons?

Tags: energy, photons, photoelectric-effect, intensity

If we take 2 case :

> Case 1: Very high energy photons and a bit less intensity
>   Case 2: less energy photons but a bit high of intensity

In both case ,both energy of photons are greater than the work function.

Since the rest energy is shown as kinetic energy of electrons and thereby showing increase in velocity and thereby a decrease in time.
Is there any chance of the lower intensity ,high photons be giving more photo current than the low energy and  a bit more intensity beam.

Comment: What do you mean by "intensity"? Do you mean the photon flux (number of photons per second), or the power intensity (power per unit area)?

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes sir.I am mentioning photon Flux as Intensity.